# How to view Stone-Cech compactification of the real line?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, c-star-algebras

I am going through Arveson's *A Short Course on Spectral Theory* and have come across an exercise constructing $\beta\mathbb{R}$ using the Gelfand map. I was wondering if there is an explicit characterisation of maximal ideals in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ the space of bounded complex values continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$? Clearly evaluation at any point in $\mathbb{R}$ is such a maximal ideal and corresponds to $\mathbb{R}\subset\beta\mathbb{R}$ but what about the others,the so called corona of $\mathbb{R}$? Every text I look up uses $\beta\mathbb{R}$ to characterise these but I don't think this is explicit?

Comment: The extra points are essentially ultrafilters and as such can't be explicit.

Comment: Ah ok. Do you know of any explicit example though of a maximal ideal which isn't the kernel of an evaluation function?

Comment: Not an example, but a reference http://mathoverflow.net/a/3876/2060

Comment: You can take any ideal, and fantasise about the maximal extensions? There is an ideal generated by $e^{-x}$ which has maximal extensions, and it cannot be in the kernel of an evaluation, as it's never  0, e.g.